# python: map() or list comprehension?

Tags: python

pythonistas: which is faster, where `a` is something like `[ str(x) for x in list(range(100)) ]`?

`ints = map(int, a)`

Or

`ints = [ int(x) for x in a ]`

Assuming `a` will be a relatively large list of strings...

Comment: map will be faster, after that it is personal preference. map happens at the c level, once you are using map without a lambda with some builtin method it will generally be faster than doing the same in a list comp

Comment: CPython doesn't have most of the effects that make benchmarks hard for languages like C or Java, so you could just [time it](https://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html) and probably get the right answer.

Comment: read this :http://stackoverflow.com/a/1247490/4941927

I think that each a one could be helpful according to your need.

Answer (score 5):

`map` looks faster *(without lambda)* on my laptop *(Macbook Pro Mid 2014, OSX 10.11.4, 16GB DDR3 ram, 2.2 GHz Intel Core i7)*:

*Tested with Python 2.7.10*

```
>>> timeit.timeit("[int(x) for x in range(100)]", number=100000)
1.6301331520080566

>>> timeit.timeit("map(int, range(100))", number=100000)
0.9462239742279053
```

However, using map with a lambda function is the slowest:

```
>>> timeit.timeit("map(lambda x: int(x), range(100))", number=100000)
2.285655994415283
```